# Web page navigates to the default path instead of going to the desired route

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a header with a 'home' button that's supposed to take me to the homepage, it 'kinda' does that but very brievely before redirecting to the login page which is the default route.
Here is the header component :

```
import {AuthService} from "../auth.service";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router : Router) {}
  logOff(): void {
    this.authService.logOff()
  }
  goToHome(): void {
    console.log(this.authService.isLoggedIn())
    this.router.navigate(['homepage']);
  }

}
```

and this is the app-routing.module :

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import {WelcomeBannerComponent} from "./welcome-banner/welcome-banner.component";
import {HomePageComponent} from "./home-page/home-page.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  // Add other routes as needed
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }, // Redirect to /login by default
  { path: 'homepage', component: HomePageComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I am console logging the state of the isLoggedIn and it's set to true, so I assume that the issue isnt with auth guard. I do not know what the problem is and any guidance even debugging would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does `HomePageComponent` do on load?

Comment: Euh  nothing ? here is the code ```// home-page.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.css'],
})
export class HomePageComponent {
  showWelcomeBanner = true;

  closeWelcomeBanner() {
    this.showWelcomeBanner = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: try using absolute path `this.router.navigate(['/homepage']);`

Comment: still not working